# Download npm dist package without having to install npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there a way I can download an npm package without having to do a `npm view XXX ...` or basically just not having to install node/npm? I'm trying to do this on a linux machine.

~EDIT~
I realize I should've added some clarification on what I'm trying to achieve here: all I need are the package's files with dependencies to be served as a static resource on cloudfront. I'm hoping npm provides a way to directly download the artefact like the way maven-central does.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. No, you should not do that. What's the constraint that you can't install npm?

Comment: Most npm packages are hosted on github - just visit the corresponding repositorsy and download the zip.

Comment: @connexo They don't have a release artefact on their GitHub page. All I'm trying to do is to fetch sources (with dependencies) and serve as a static resource on cloudfront. I was just hoping npm provides a way to directly download the artefact like the way maven does.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can access to the raw package using the NPM api.

`https://registry.npmjs.org/{package-name}/{version}`

The url above will give you a JSON response containing the package metadata. The package property `dist.tarball` contains an url where the package can be downloaded.

Keep in mind you have to install the dependencies of the package on your own

**Example:**

https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/4.17.10

---

[NPM API documentation](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md)

Answer (score -2):

Download lib folder from github.com-get all files within it

Put all the files next to your node application in the same folder.
at the top of your file append it like sooo....

var ""  = require("./""")