# How to get the *.min.js file from npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, video.js

I want to get the .js file from a package but I can't do it, I don't know how npm/yarn works and I need the file since my page is pure html.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-landscape-fullscreen

Comment: then use cdn...

Comment: Yes, I agree totally.  Using CDN is much more straightforward than the 'npm' approach, which has the extra burden of requiring you to install and understand tools such as 'npm'. ( I wish more of the examples/tutorials started off my explaining the much simpler CDN approach.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download npm dist package without having to install npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933603/download-npm-dist-package-without-having-to-install-npm)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comments, you can use one of a few CDN services that build the dist files for you, such as [jsdlvr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) or [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/), e.g.

- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-landscape-fullscreen@1.2.6/dist/videojs-landscape-fullscreen.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/videojs-landscape-fullscreen@1.2.6/dist/videojs-landscape-fullscreen.min.js