# How to get npm package access from the command line?

Tags: npm

I can't seem to find any way to determine an npm packages access level in the npmjs.org registry without looking at the web page. I assumed there would be some way to get this information from the command line, but neither `npm access` nor `npm view` seem to provide this information.

Is there any way to determine whether a package is public or private from the command line?

I realize that it would be possible to screen scrape this from the npmjs.org site, but I'm discounting that as infeasible for all the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Workable if ugly:

- [Attempt to download a package using `curl`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933603/download-npm-dist-package-without-having-to-install-npm) If successful, it's public.
- If necessary to ensure the package exists or is private and accessible to you, you would still need to check for package with `npm view` or something.

Thanks to @charles-lowell for prompt.