# I cant install fecli using npm, it always say unsupported engine, what to do to solve this and run fecli

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, visual-studio-code, node-modules

```
$ npm i fecli -g
npm WARN deprecated ejs@1.0.0: Critical security bugs fixed in 2.5.5
C:\Users\USER\${HOME}\.npm-packages\fecli -> 
C:\Users\USER\${HOME}\.npm-packages\node_modules\fecli\bin\fecli.js
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fecli@0.4.0: wanted: {"node":"^0.10.32"} (current: {"node":"14.17.0","npm":"6.14.13"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fecli@0.4.0
```

- fecli@0.4.0
  removed 6 packages, updated 1 package and moved 49 packages in 16.697s

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2w7G.png)

I have install 0.10.32 as required then it say 4 .0.0 version required, I don't know what to do

Comment: You could download the package by hand and change its package.json to make it compatible.
You could go to their github page and add an issue to their project.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to download the required package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933603/download-npm-dist-package-without-having-to-install-npm

Comment: Thank you for guiding me, actually, it was solved by installing semver dependency